# pdf document is shown differently on adobe acrobat and other visors

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

Well, this is weird.

We've received a pdf document. This document is a franken-pdf built from a web source (ilovepdf.com)

When we open this pdf document with acrobat reader (2019.010.20091) there are three pages that are shown blank. Also, file signature cannot be validated.

If we open it on Chrome's pdf extension, those three pages are shown correctly, and if we use FoxIt Reader the three pages are shown correctly and the signature validates perfectly.

Now we are struggling, because we need to know if we accept this document or not, and, from a legal point of view, the inconsistence between signature validation in different visors could be an issue.

So... our theory so far is that something in this ilovepdf.com web is adding some background code to the document which Acrobat identifies as garbage and makes it cancel some pages, that alteration breaks signature validation and here our problem... but we are not sure and don't know how to confirm it.

Does anyone suffered a similar behaviour and discovered the reason behind the problem? Anyone knows why different visors show different results of the same document?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: @mkl Sadly, due to legal reasons, I cannot share or lend the document :(

Comment: Then please try to achieve the same effect with a document you can share. If you succeed, great, then we can analyze the issue. If you don't succeed, though, chances are there is something very special about your document and you should not hope for an answer without allowing an analysis of the document in question.

Comment: @mkl that's exactly my opinion. In fact we've tried to reproduce the problem creating ourselves a pdf document on the same site, but to no success. I'd like to send you the file to analyze, but lawyers at my company forbid me to do so :( I hate lawyers...